Facebook Permissions Application - test app permissions
We have an application with Facebook that has been successfully granted several permissions in the past. I know that the process of getting app permissions with meta has always been unnecessarily difficult and I expected nothing less when applying for the 'Page Public Content Access' permission.
However, this has turned out to be substantially more challenging than predicted.
Initially we tried accessing the permission from our currently 'live' application which didn't work and were quickly guided by meta support to create a test application (a copy of the parent application) and attempt to use the endpoints/permissions based on this 'development' application.
This is what we did and we added the 'pages_show_list' and 'pages_read_engagement' permissions before requesting an access token in order to test the 'pages/search' endpoint that we would be screencasting for our permissions approval.
This though is giving us the exact same results
{ "error": {
    "message": "(#10) This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature. Refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions#manage-pages, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#page-public-metadata-access for details.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "AICjKBRUbuIP8RrzxSfYG1C"
  }
}

I feel like I've read the documentation a million times and it has not improved my understanding, nor my mood towards their application mechanism.
What are we doing wrong here?

Please do not add bad tags or meta commentary into your posts, or re-add them when users remove them.

I don't agree with your changes. The facebook tag clearly directs people to issues relating to facebook graph api and the organisation that owns facebook is called Meta.

The [tag:facebook] tag is a meta tag and should not be used. The [tag:facebook-graph-api] tag is actually that tag that directs people to issues relating to the Facebook Graph API. Using the [tag:meta] tag to refer to the company Meta is even more of a meta tag than [tag:facebook] and, if you bother to read the tag description, not what the [tag:meta] tag is even for.
